# How to get Current Remote DateTime in C# windows Application

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, c#-2.0

I am developing an c# 2.0 application where there will be around 5 clients and all are connected with internet.Remote MySql is storing the data and working as a Server.

**I need to display the current DateTime and open a form(with some
 information) on every client at the same time after every 5 minutes.**

I am using the following code to update system date time

```
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern bool SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME st);
```

Form_load event

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
con.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select  UTC_TIMESTAMP()", con);
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
      {
                DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]);    
                SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
                // dt = dt.AddMinutes(330);
                st.wYear = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Year);
                st.wMonth = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Month);
                st.wDay = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Day);
                st.wHour = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Hour);
                st.wMinute = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Minute);
                st.wSecond = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Second);
                SetSystemTime(ref st);
     }
     dr.Close();
     cmd.Dispose();
```

Then using the **`DateTime.Now`** to get the current date and time. But the current time is not same in all the clients.Its Differs around 5-20 seconds from each other.

Is there any way to get the current Date and time (my locale Date Time) through internet.

Note :I already write the code so that Client will not be able change the time after opening the software.

Comment: You need a time server.

Comment: @McNets  what is that? How to implement that?

Comment: Is a server used to synchronize clocks, like a domain controler, time.microsoft.com is a time server. Take a look at [NTP Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)